# Should I accept this Web developer job offer or keep looking?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, new-job

I'm looking for a front end developer job. My ideal job would be a React JS role, i.e. a mix of HTML, SCSS and React. I have no commercial React experience so the job hunting can be a bit difficult. I have been learning React by myself for a few months and built several projects with React. I feel pretty comfortable with React now, just have no idea what a commercial React application would look like.

I've been looking for a while and now there is a software house who's willing to offer me a Web Developer position. As you may have noticed, it is a web developer not a front end developer, so rather than writing React code daily, this role could be a mixture of UI design, HTML/SCSS and some coding. The company mentioned that they have recruited an Angular developer, but whether using Angular or React in the long term is unclear, my understanding is they will use Angular, but using React is also possible, or possibly no React at all. (I'm not certain at the moment)

I'm a bit undecided now, I don't mind doing some UI and HTML/SCSS, but I don't want to be only doing it. I definitely want to write some React code. Here are the pro and cons of accepting it (assuming salary is good):

Pros: start working immediately, having income, potential of working with other front end developers on React projects;

Cons: might not be able to code in React (compare to a pure React job), if so my commercial React skills are still weak.

Should I resist the impulse of accepting this job and keep looking until I find my ideal one, or be sensible and accept it consider it is a pandemic and jobs are hard to find?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How long have React developers been needed?
How long will React developers be needed?

From my understanding, front-end languages come and go.

So instead of React, you'll learn Angular? Then you will have professional experience with Angular. And you can always list that you are also skilled with React, but not to the level of Angular.

Does the above seem viable. Yes? Then-

Have you asked the company if you are able to pursue own development? Some companies set aside 4 hrs for exploration?
Will you delve deep into developing with Angular, or will it be more artsy? Not developing in front-end seems out of alignment with long-term goals.